# Как вывести минимальную цену товара в категории Django?

Tags: django, django-orm, jinja2, django-filter

Подскажите, в чем ошибка? Нужно вывести минимальную и максимальную цену товара.
Views.py:

```html
class CategoryView(ListView):
    """Категория товаров"""
    model = Item
    #queryset = Item.objects.order_by('?')
    paginate_by = 24
    template_name = "category.html"


    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        queryset = Item.objects.all()
        category = self.kwargs['slug']
        if category is not None:
            queryset = Item.objects.filter(category__slug=category).order_by('?')
        return queryset

    def get_prices(self, **kwargs):
        prices = Item.objects.all()
        category = self.kwargs['slug']
        if category is not None:
            prices = Item.objects.filter(category__slug=category).aggregate(Max('price'), Min('price'))
        return prices
```

В шаблоне страницы категории вывожу так:

```html
{{ prices.price__min }}
```

Ничего не выводится. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: К чему эта функция? `get_prices`

Comment: Чтобы вывести минимальную или максимальную цену товара в категории.